# Which tense is more appropriate in the following context?

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

I was reading an English textbooks, in which there are examples of present continues tenses:

> I've lost my key again. I'm **always** losing things.
>
> You are **always** watching television. You should do something more
>   active.

As far as this are an actions, which are repeated always I would guess that this kind of thoughts should be expressed in present tense form.
So why they keep them in present continues tense, rather then in present simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The present continuous in this case (with words "always" or "constantly") is used to emphasize the idea that something happens so often that becomes characteristic of a person, group or thing. Notice that the meaning is like simple present, but sometimes with negative emotion, irritation or disapproval.

> She is always coming to school late.
>   He is constantly talking. I wish he would shut up.
>   I don't like them because they are always complaining.

Comment: But the use of present continuous to express habitual action does not have anything to do with "th negative emotion, irritation or disapproval." Consider *José  is always finding better ways to improve his English* and *You are always watching television when you should be: after you've finished your homework*.

Comment: I should have written *sometimes*